# Reading a line that contains characters and numbers and writing values separately

Tags: c++, string

I have a file that contains the following line:

> config101010000101010111000adaptorname1010000101010010101adaptordescription10101010100001111111ipaddress10111010000010000

I know how to read and write the whole line but couldn't figure out how to write it to the file as: (seperate those word characters from integer numbers by (:) and write each word to seperate line as in below)

```
config : 101010000101010111000 
adaptorname: 1010000101010010101
adaptordescription: 10101010100001111111
ipaddress: 10111010000010000
```

Comment: that really depends on how you loaded it and store it.

Comment: Please show your code to read and parse the input file. I am having trouble understanding how writing it in the requested format is not trivial after you read and parse.

Comment: assume that we have a string like "config101010000101010111000adaptorname1010000101010010101adaptordescription10101010100001111111ipaddress10111010000010000" i want to seprate the chars 'config' first then write the coming numbers after it then on new line i wanna write 'adaptorname' then upcpming numbers and so on. ( my could is so basic i used getline to parse it and write it the file so its of no use i have just started but couldnt understand as i am new to c++)

Comment: @user3521035 I do not think there was a problem understanding your question.  However you still have not posted your c++ code to read the file so its hard to help. This is not a homework writing site, we can not just give you the answer.

Comment: Also I am not sure this code is a duplicate of the linked. That is until I see the code from the OP.